# Preform Math Operations to a List in Dart

Tags: arrays, list, dart, math

I have to get an input from the user and split it into a list by using the split() function.

Now I need to do some math operations like addition and multiplication with the elements of the list.

I'm getting an error when running the following code:

```dart
stdout.write("Input:"); 
var input = stdin.readLineSync(); stdout.write(input); 

List<String?> splitted = input!.split(','); stdout.write(splitted); 

//Addition: 
stdout.write(splitted[0] + splitted[1] + splitted[2] + splitted[3] + splitted[4]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After converting the strings, you can use [reduce function](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html):

```dart
void main() {
  String values = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9';
  List<String> splitted = values.split(',');
  print(splitted); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  // Convert the list of strings to a list of integers
  List<int> converted = splitted.map((e)=>int.parse(e)).toList(); 
  // Reduce the list as the sum of its elements
  int result = converted.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  print(result); // 45
}
```